# Definite Integral $\int_2^4\frac{\sqrt{\log(9-x)}}{\sqrt{\log(9-x)}+\sqrt{\log(3+x)}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How can I find the value of this following definite integral?

> $$\int_2^4\frac{\sqrt{\log(9-x)}}{\sqrt{\log(9-x)}+\sqrt{\log(3+x)}}dx$$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HINT:

Use $$I=\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx$$

and $$2I=\int_a^bf(x)dx+\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx=\int_a^b\left(f(x)+f(a+b-x)\right)dx$$

Observe that if
$\displaystyle g(x)=\sqrt{\ln(9-x)},$
$\displaystyle g(4+2-x)=\sqrt{\ln(9-(6-x))}=\sqrt{\ln(x+3)}$

Comment: In general, $\displaystyle I=\int_a^b\frac{g(x)}{g(x)+g(a+b-x)}dx=\int_a^b\frac{g(a+b-x)}{g(a+b-x)+g(x)}dx $

$\displaystyle\implies 2I=\int_a^b dx=\cdots$