# Integral $\int_{1}^{2011} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{2012 - x} + \sqrt{x}}dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, analysis

Evaluate:

$$\int_{1}^{2011} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{2012 - x} + \sqrt{x}}dx$$

Using **real methods only.**

I am not sure what to do.

I tried finding a power series, which was too ugly.

I just need some hints, not an answer to do this integral, this is from the MIT Integration bee 2012.

Comment: Try the substitution $u=2012-x$

Answer (score 14, accepted):

HINT:

As $\displaystyle\int_a^bf(x)\ dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)\ dx$

So, if $\int_a^bf(x)\ dx=I,$

$$2I=\int_a^b[f(x)+f(a+b-x)]\ dx$$

Comment: How does this property suffice?

Comment: @Amad27, if $f(x)=\dfrac{\sqrt x }{\sqrt{2012 - x} + \sqrt x}, f(1+2011-x)=?$

Comment: $f(2012 - x) = \frac{\sqrt{2012 - x}}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{2012 - x}}$

Comment: @Amad27, $f(x)+f(1+2011-x)=?$

Comment: $f(x) + f(2012 -x ) = \frac{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{2012 - x}}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{2012 - x}} = 1$ So the integral answer is 2011 - 1 = 2010?

Comment: Divided by 2 = 1005

Comment: @Amad27, Yes. See also : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578957/definite-integral-int-24-frac-sqrt-log9-x-sqrt-log9-x-sqrt-log3 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439851/evaluate-the-integral-int-frac-pi2-0-frac-sin3x-sin3x-cos3xdx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19573/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-amad27).

Answer (score 6):

$$I=\int_{1}^{2011} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{2012 - x} + \sqrt{x}}dx$$

Let $u=2012-x$ then $$I=\int_{2011}^{1} \frac{\sqrt{2012-u}}{\sqrt{2012 - u} + \sqrt{u}}du=-\int_{1}^{2011} \frac{\sqrt{2012-x}}{\sqrt{2012 - x} + \sqrt{x}}dx$$
Thus $$2I=\int_{1}^{2011} \frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{2012 - x}}{\sqrt{2012 - x} + \sqrt{x}}dx$$

Comment: Hello friend, you have a small error, the integration limits are $ u (1) $, $ u(2011) $

Answer (score 0):

It is known that : $$\int_a^b\frac{f(x)}{f(a+b-x)+f(x)}dx=\frac{a+b}{2}$$You should remember this. After making sure that this is the case, you get the answer as $1005$.