# How to evaluate this definite integral: $\int_3^6 \frac{\sqrt x}{\sqrt x+\sqrt{9-x}} dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Evaluate $$\int_3^6{{\sqrt x}\over {\sqrt x+\sqrt{9-x}}}dx $$

I understand some tricky substitution is required to work this out but I can't decide what . May be its a too easy  question to be asked on this board but please give me some hint on the substitution. I can work the rest hopefully.

Comment: have u tried to rationalize the denominator?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1073120/integral-int-12011-frac-sqrtx-sqrt2012-x-sqrtxdx

Comment: @AhmedHussein : ok I got $18{\sin^2 \theta \cos \theta}\over {\sin\theta + \cos \theta}$

Comment: The tricky substitution you need is $u = 9-x$.

Comment: Check out Nelsen's short paper *Symmetry and Integration*: http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/mathdl/CMJ/Nelsen39-41.pdf

Comment: @labbhattacharjee : thanks. that solved my problem . Now I find the substitution Ahmed Hussain suggested : $x=9\sin^\theta$  interesting . Can you help me a little to proceed with that now . Thanks

Comment: @user80631,, You will reach something like: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439851/evaluate-the-integral-int-frac-pi2-0-frac-sin3x-sin3x-cos3xdx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Recall that
$$\int_a^b f(x)dx = \int_a^b f(a+b-x)dx$$
Hence, if $I = \displaystyle \int_3^6 \dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{9-x}}dx$, we then have
$$I = \int_3^6 \dfrac{\sqrt{9-x}}{\sqrt{9-x}+\sqrt{9-(9-x)}}dx = \int_3^6 \dfrac{\sqrt{9-x}}{\sqrt{9-x}+\sqrt{x}}dx$$
Hence, we have that
$$I + I = \int_3^6 \dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{9-x}}dx + \int_3^6 \dfrac{\sqrt{9-x}}{\sqrt{9-x}+\sqrt{x}}dx = \int_3 ^6 dx = 3$$
Hence, the integral is $\dfrac32$.