# Find $\int_0^\infty\frac{x\log x}{(1+x^2)^2}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Evaluate $$
> \int_0^\infty\frac{x\log x}{(1+x^2)^2}dx
> $$

$$
\int\frac{x}{(1+x^2)^2}dx=\frac{-1}{2(1+x^2)}\\
\int_0^\infty\frac{x\log x}{(1+x^2)^2}dx=
\bigg[\log x\frac{-1}{2(1+x^2)}\bigg]_0^\infty-\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x}.\frac{-1}{2(1+x^2)}dx\\
=0+\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{2x(1+x^2)}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int\bigg[\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x}{1+x^2}\bigg]dx\\
=\frac{1}{2}[\log x]^\infty_0-\frac{1}{4}[\log|1+x^2|]_0^\infty=\frac{1}{4}\log\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\\
=\bigg[\frac{1}{4}\log\frac{1}{\dfrac{1}{x^2}+1}\bigg]_0^\infty
$$

Is there a better substitution that I can make to evaluate thi definite integral ?

**Note:** The solution given in my reference is $0$

Similar question is asked @[Prove that $\int_0^\infty \frac{x\,\log x}{(1+x^2)^2} = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2473234/prove-that-int-0-infty-fracx-log-x1x22-0) but that is about the convergence of the given integral, here I am looking for a better and obvious substitution that will make the above definite integral easier to solve. But, hint about the solution is found there, Thanks @`lab bhattacharjee`

Comment: I'm rusty, but this feels like something suited to contour integration, if you're familiar with that/complex analysis.

Comment: Did you try to split the integral into $\int_0^1 + \int_1^\infty$ and use the substitution $u = 1/x$ in the last integral?

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar Nope, how do I even see if such a substitution helps ?

Comment: @ss1729 The integral reminded me of $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \log(x)/(1+x^2) \,\mathrm{d}x$ and so I thought to use the same "trick". If you look at the plot it looks something like this https://imgur.com/a/BZgNKNP. Thus it is tempting to split the integral at 1 and see if the integral over 0 to 1 sort of cancels out the integral from 1 to $\infty$. Another point is that $\log x = - \log (1/x)$. In broader terms your integral satisfies my functional equation here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/691064/18908 $R(x) = x/(1+x^2)^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks `@lab bhattacharjee`, for the hint.

Set $x=\tan t\implies dx=\sec^2t.dt$
$$
I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\tan t.\log(\tan t).\sec^2t.dt}{\sec^4t}=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin t.\cos t\log(\tan t).dt\\
=\int_0^{\pi/4}\sin t.\cos t.\log(\tan t).dt+\int_0^{\pi/4}\sin t.\cos t.\log(\cot t).dt\\
=\int_0^{\pi/4}\sin t.\cos t.\log(\tan t).dt-\int_0^{\pi/4}\sin t.\cos t.\log(\tan t).dt=0
$$

Answer (score 4):

Note that, with $x=\frac1t$,

$$\int_1^\infty\frac{x\log x}{(1+x^2)^2}dx
=- \int_0^1\frac{t\log t}{(1+t^2)^2}dt$$

Thus, the integral is evaluated to zero.

Comment: This is a nice substitution but how do I even imagine about such a substitution would help in the first place ?

Comment: @ss1729 - There are numerous such integrals, with $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}=0$ being most known. I guess you have seen enough of them, you’d always have a watchful eye for it.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x\ln(x)}{(1+x^2)^2}dx$$
$$x=\dfrac{1}{t}$$

$$1=-\dfrac{1}{t^2}\dfrac{dt}{dx}$$
$$dx=-\dfrac{1}{t^2}dt$$

$$I=\int_{\infty}^{0}\dfrac{t\ln(t)}{(t^2+1)^2}dt$$
$$I=-\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{t\ln(t)}{(t^2+1)^2}dt$$

As integration is independent of change of variable

$$I=-I$$
$$2I=0$$
$$I=0$$

So by this method we easily got answer as zero.