# Definite integral (exact value): Help solving this definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Here's the integral:

$$\int_{1}^{5}{\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{6-x}+\sqrt{x}}dx}$$

tried rationalising the function:

$$\frac{\sqrt{x\left( 6-x \right)}-x}{6-2x}$$

which doesn't get me anywhere with substitution or integration by parts

---

I would appreciate if someone were to help me through hints/techniques (besides numerical methods).

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578957/definite-integral-int-24-frac-sqrt-log9-x-sqrt-log9-x-sqrt-log3

Comment: thanks, that clears it up a bit more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$\displaystyle I = \int_{1}^{5}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{6-x}+\sqrt{x}}dx.................(1)$$

Now Using $$\displaystyle \bullet \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx = \int_{a}^{b}f(a+b-x)dx$$

So Replace $x\rightarrow (1+5-x) = (6-x)$ in equation $(1)$

So we get $$\displaystyle I = \int_{1}^{5}\frac{\sqrt{6-x}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{6-x}}dx..........(2)$$

Now add  above two  equation, we get

$$\displaystyle 2I = \int_{1}^{5}\frac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{6-x}}{\sqrt{6-x}+\sqrt{x}}dx = \int_{1}^{5}1dx =\left[x\right]_{1}^{5}= 4$$

So we get $$\displaystyle \displaystyle I = \int_{1}^{5}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{6-x}+\sqrt{x}}dx= 2$$

Comment: The limit should be $a$ to $b$  not $1$ to $b$

Comment: so you took $u=a+b-x$ and the limits should be b to a

Comment: is it a to b or

Comment: Thanks  lab bhattacharjee I have edited it. Yes inspad it is from $a$ to $b$

Comment: why, when $x=a$  $u=b$

Comment: oh forgot the $du/dx$ nvm

Comment: Now how would I realise such a thing under exam conditions..

Comment: You should read properties of definite Integrals and examples related to such properties. Then you will able to solve these type of questions.

Comment: do you have a good link on these? i'm googling it now anyway