# Show / Prove this two integrals are equal

Tags: integration, analysis

If $n$ and $m$ are positive and integer numbers prove that

$$\int_0^1 x^m \cdot(1-x)^ndx =  \int _0^1 x^n \cdot(1-x)^mdx.$$

I have tried to substitute $u=1-x$ but I got nowhere.

Comment: The substitution $u=1-x$ suffices.

Comment: Does the star denote a convolution or a multiplication?

Comment: Use  $$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx,$$  See also : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439851/evaluate-the-integral-int-frac-pi2-0-frac-sin3x-sin3x-cos3xdx/439856#439856    https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1073120/integral-int-12011-frac-sqrtx-sqrt2012-x-sqrtxdx/1073121#1073121       https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578957/definite-integral-int-24-frac-sqrt-log9-x-sqrt-log9-x-sqrt-log3/578960#578960

Comment: Where did you actually get stuck? The substitution $u=1-x$ works perfectly.

Comment: I substituted but totally forgot to evaluate the integration limits in u

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your substitution is correct:

$$\begin{align}\int\limits_0^1 x^m (1-x)^n \,\mathrm d\,x ~&=~  \int\limits_{1}^{0} (1-u)^m u^n (-\mathrm d u) &&[x\gets 1-u, \mathrm dx\gets (-\mathrm du)] \\ &= \int\limits_0^1 (1-u)^mu^n\,\mathrm d\,u \\ &=\int\limits_0^1 (1-x)^mx^n\,\mathrm d\,x && \text{alpha replacement}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 6):

The substitution is correct.

Let $u=1-x$. Then

\begin{align}
\int_0^1x^m(1-x)^ndx&=\int_1^0(1-u)^mu^n(-1)du\\
&=\int_0^1(1-u)^mu^ndu\\
&=\int_0^1x^n(1-x)^mdx\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively: Note the Beta and Gamma functions are related as follows: 
$$B(x,y)=\int_0^1t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}dt=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}=\frac{(x-1)!(y-1)!}{(x+y-1)!}.$$

Hence: $$B(m+1,n+1)=\int_0^1x^m(1-x)^ndx=\frac{m!\cdot n!}{(m+n+1)!}=$$
$$\frac{n!\cdot m!}{(n+m+1)!}=\int_0^1x^n(1-x)^mdx=B(n+1,m+1).$$